# Ranking for duplicate data

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have a data set below.

```
id  val
q1  abc
q2  abc
q4  qwe
q3  xyz
```

I want to give it a number like below in SQL in HIVE.

```
id  val  ranking
q1  abc  1 
q2  abc  1
q4  qwe  2
q3  xyz  3
```

The conventional functions like row_number, rank is not giving me the desired result.

Comment: how would you like the ranking to happen?

Comment: Did you try `dense_rank() over (order by val)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by val) as ranking
from t;
```

In the event that you don't want to order by the value itself, but rather by the position:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by minid) as ranking
from (select t.*, min(id) over (partition by val) as minid
      from t
     ) t;
```